# how to monitor listener performance in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

hi I'm using spring kafka and i have a kafka consumer like below.

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "myGroup", autoStartup = "true", concurrency = "3")
  public void consumeAssignment(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                                @Header(required = false, name = KafkaHeaders.BATCH_CONVERTED_HEADERS)
                                        List<HashMap<String, byte[]>> headers,
                                @Header(required = false, name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                                @Payload(required = false) List<String> messages)
```

I have provided MeterRegistry for my kafka consumer constructor like below.

```
  public KafkaConsumer(MeterRegistry registry) {
    
  }
```

I need to get the time Kafka took to process my messages. I know that there are two timers maintained; one for successful calls to the listener and one for failures. What are the changes that i need to do in order to have those metrics ? is there any example ?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the system time at the start and end of the "processing", then update the registry, accordingly. Kafka doesn't provide that out of the box.

You could try playing around with `@Timed` annotation, but adding your own numbers will probably be more consistent.

[Spring-Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#monitoring-listener-performance) will add listener success/error metrics if you have Micrometer on the classpath (e.g. [enable Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.monitoring) + wire in a MeterRegistry bean to the app context)

Comment: this is available https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#monitoring-listener-performance, but dont know how to apply it.

Comment: Have you enabled Spring Actuator? Did you look at the metrics endpoint while the app runs?

Comment: As that link says, the timers are enabled by default, as long as there is a `MeterRegistry` in the application context. If they are not there, provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: thank you, metrics are there under the name of spring_kafka_listener.

Comment: i have one more thing, imagine i do some processing part inside my consumer. Does that time also included in the success scenario time ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't used spring-kafka metrics.